# Background gradient ends and doesn't continue

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

I have a div under my body element. It has that background CSS:

```
-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #000000 0%, #30FF40 400px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
```

Inside of my div there is a datatable (a jqGrid table). I think after my page loads that grid table gets a space on my page. So my gradient background ends up somewhere and bottom of my page has a whitespace(other pages doesn't have datatables are OK).

How can I solve that?

**EDIT:**

My problem is like that:
[image]

**PS:**

I found which causes it. I have a div element that includes my datatable:

```
<div id="cont">
...
</div>
```

When I open my webpage it becomes like:

```
<div id="cont" style="height: 602px;">
...
</div>
```

I changed the `#cont` styles to `height:auto` etc. but something overrides it even I write an inline CSS definition. It has a CSS like:

```
#cont {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 960px;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my Answer as well :) Some Jquery is applying height to your ID #cont

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body{ margin:0px; padding:0px; background: #fff; min-width:300px/*480px*/; height:100%;}
.yourClass
{
margin:0; padding:0; display:block; overflow:hidden;
    background: #444444;    background-repeat:repeat;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #8db849, #444444);
    width:100%; min-height:100%; 
}
#cont {
  height:320px;/*Assumed height by Jquery / whaterver, you can remove while real time*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 960px;
  max-width: 80%;
  background:#0099CC;
}
</style>



<div class="yourClass">
    <div id="cont">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

It works for me, cheers!

Comment: Try to check if jqGrid table is adding any position:absolute, some time it take ur grid content out of flow, if so then u need to find the height using additional Jquery say var jqGridHeight = $("#jqGrid ") and create div in dom and apply this new height, take care that ur new div is inside the Gradient div. It another try!

Answer (score 1):

```
-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #000000 0%, #30FF40 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
```

What happens if you remove the 400px limit?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, took me a bit to find this, but here's your answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient. Check out the 'Notes' section. Essentially, it's a "bug" wherein the background won't fill the entire container by default.

Basically, use the edit suggested by @Jonas G. Drange (change the last value to 100%), and then add a new rule to the CSS sheet:

```
html /*<-- or whatever the container element is */
{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Viola.

Comment: Still having the same problem.